# DetailView not showing data

Tags: python, django, listview, detailview

I am trying to display a `ListView` of items that when clicked opens the respective `DetailView` for that item.  This is a pretty straightforward thing to do in Django, but I'm running into some trouble with it.

I have successfully created a `ListView`, but I can't get the `DetailView` to display the information for each item.

I am building a password safe. The `ListView` lists all the passwords saved, and the `DetailView` is the view/edit page for each password. And yes, I realize actually putting a password safe on the internet is a terrible idea, it's just a test project :)

My `PasswordSafe` class:

```
class PasswordSafe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    pwWebsite = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pwUsername = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pwEmail = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pwPassword = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2, __str__ on Python 3
        return self.pwWebsite

User.passwordSafe = property(lambda u: PasswordSafe.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

My `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from models import PasswordSafe

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^passwordSafe/$', ListView.as_view(queryset=PasswordSafe.objects.all().order_by('-pwWebsite')[:10], template_name = 'userprofile/passwordSafe_list.html')),
    url(r'^passwordSafe/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=PasswordSafe, template_name='userprofile/passwordSafe.html')),
    ]
```

I use the following code successfully in my `ListView` template (`passwordSafe_list.html`):

```
{% for passwordSafe in object_list %}

    <h2><a href="/accounts/passwordSafe/{{passwordSafe.id}}">{{ passwordSafe.pwWebsite }}</a></h2>

{% endfor %}
```

However, when I try to use the passwordSafe data in my `Detailview` (the `passwordSafe.html` template), nothing shows up.  I use the following code to try and change the title:

```
<title>{% block title %} | Edit {{ passwordSafe.pwWebsite }} Password{% endblock %}</title>
```

This should show a title something like "Password Safe | Edit Google Password", but `passwordSafe.pwWebsite` returns with nothing.  Am I doing something wrong in trying to reference passwordSafe from this template?  I know I haven't passed a query set like I did with the `ListView`, but I'm not sure if that's part of the problem or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `DetailView`, Django [uses the model name in lowercase, by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name), if you haven't set `context_object_name`.

```
{{ passwordsafe.pwWebsite }}
```